# failing to import a .gltf file with webpack

Tags: webpack, three.js, webpack-4, gltf

I'm struggling to import .gltf files with Webpack (gatsby project with react+webpack+react-three-fiber).

In development mode, I get this error:

```
This relative module was not found:
⠀
* ../../static/gltf/bear_v2.gltf in ./src/components/CanvasWrapper.js
error ✖ ｢wdm｣:
ERROR in ./src/components/CanvasWrapper.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../static/gltf/bear_v2.gltf' in '/Volumes/Data/DOCUMENTS/_htdocs/slenterende-beer/src/components'
 @ ./src/components/CanvasWrapper.js 19:0-55 25:12-21 149:10-19
 @ ./src/pages/index.js
 @ ./.cache/sync-requires.js
 @ ./.cache/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?path=/__webpack_hmr&reload=true&overlay=false ./.cache/app
info ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

When I switched between `import` and `require` during development time, it suddenly works. When I switch and restart the project, it fails again (until I switch). I think this is some strange cache issue(?).

I'm using `gltf-webpack-loader` to load the file.
The file is now placed in `/static/gltf/model.gltf` but before had them in `/assets/` which wasn't liked by webpack I suppose.

webpack rules:
https://github.com/flowen/slenterendebeer/blob/master/gatsby-node.js

loading code:
https://github.com/flowen/slenterendebeer/blob/master/src/components/CanvasWrapper.js

imports are at line 6 and line 15

and these are the build errors (on netlify):

```
10:02:42 PM:   Error: ./static/gltf/bear.gltf
10:02:42 PM:   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './-0.707' in '/opt/build/repo/static/g  ltf'
10:02:42 PM:   resolve './-0.707' in '/opt/build/repo/static/gltf'
10:02:42 PM:     using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./static/gltf)
10:02:42 PM:       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:       using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./sta  tic/gltf/-0.707)
10:02:42 PM:         no extension
10:02:42 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707 doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:         .mjs
10:02:42 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.mjs doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:         .js
10:02:42 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.js doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:         .jsx
10:02:42 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.jsx doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:         .wasm
10:02:42 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.wasm doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:         .json
10:02:42 PM:           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.json doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:         as directory
10:02:42 PM:           /opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707 doesn't exist
10:02:42 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707]
10:02:42 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.mjs]
10:02:42 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.js]
10:02:42 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.jsx]
10:02:45 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:02:42 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.wasm]
10:02:42 PM:   [/opt/build/repo/static/gltf/-0.707.json]
10:02:42 PM:    @ ./static/gltf/bear.gltf ./-0.707
```

Comment: what are you using gltf-webpack-loader for? you should be able to just get the path with "const modelPath = require('../../static/gltf/bear.gltf')" and then load it "new GLTFLoader().load(modelPath, (res)..."

Comment: @TomaszZieliński then I get this message: * ../assets/gltf/bear.gltf in ./src/components/CanvasWrapper.js
error ✖ ｢wdm｣:
ERROR in ./src/components/CanvasWrapper.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/gltf/bear.gltf'